# CRUD view link does not work in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a problem here. I just started to learn with Yii2 framework and tried to create a CRUD view. I created it by using `yii2` documentation and the following link to open the view: `http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=employee%2Findex`. But somehow this link doesn't work. Could someone explain me why? Maybe is there something I need to write in my code to display it? Thank you for the help.

Comment: you have error  ?

Comment: Oh yea, but it's a long one on white screen. Simply it says that page not found, but that page is there, so im confused

Comment: if you don't show the error  .. i can't help you ..

Comment: @scaisEdge here is the link of the error: http://imageshack.com/a/img922/7590/5yGkl1.png

Answer (score 0):

At first, i guess u should add a rule into the UrlManager in your config :

```
'components' => [
...
    'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    ]
]
```

Just to make the urls are simple, like **http://localhost/employee/index**

Anyway, you should check the **index.php** view in **views/employee/** directory. If it exist, check the **actionIndex** in **EmployeeController** and check the place where are render of **index** view

Answer (score 0):

I see that no one solved your problem. According to your error image I guess that you haven't moved your CRUD generated files from `views/employee` directory to `controller directory`.

If you have named your controller `site`, just move the files from `views/employee` to `views/site` and try to open your webpage.

Hope this helps